If friction is not proportional to velocity, why do we model it as such when considering damped oscillations?
Early in our study of mechanics, we learn that friction is usually proportional only to normal force, without dependence on velocity. However, during our studies of damped oscillations, we often model the damping force as proportional to velocity, since this produces an equation of motion that is easily solvable. However, if you were to construct a mass-spring system on a table, where friction is proportional only to normal force, what would the equation of motion and its possible solutions look like?

Who taught you that friction is not proportional to velocity?

@my2cts OP is talking about static or kinetic friction which is independent of velocity.

Does this answer your question? What is the Equation of Motion for a Harmonic Motion Damped by Constant Friction?


If friction is not proportional to velocity, why do we model it as
such when considering damped oscillations?

In kinetic friction problems the kinetic friction force is generally considered independent of velocity (though in reality it isn't). But the dissipation of energy in the form of heat (rate of heat dissipation due to friction work) is proportional to velocity. I believe that's what's being modeled as proportional to velocity, not the friction force.
Hope this helps.
